# Removing blank objects within a tuple

Tags: python, list, object, tuples

I have the following dataset and would like to remove the blank objects at the very end. In other words I want to retain only the first 3 objects within each tuple. I've highlighted the items that i'm trying to get rid off.

```
(['2639123', 'LOUNGE & ENVIRONMENT', '"The lounge area was very dated and dirty. The garbage can by the popcorn was disgusting. The floor was very dirty, and the chairs were very dated and worn. "', '', ''], ['2652943', 'LOUNGE & ENVIRONMENT', '"The lounge area seemed clean and updated, but it didn\'t feel very warm or welcoming. It seemed slightly closed off. The monkey I met all acknowledged me in a polite manner as I encountered them."', '', ''])
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So are you using this for interactive fiction, or did you just set up your example that way?

Comment: i just set it up this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
>>> data= (['a','','b',''],['c','',''])
>>> tuple([e for e in l if e] for l in data)
(['a', 'b'], ['c'])
```

With variable lengths:

```
>>> data = ([],[''],['a', ''], ['b', 'c', '', 'd', '', 'e'])
>>> tuple([e for e in l if e] for l in data)
([], [], ['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

If you want only the first three non-empty items of each list:

```
tuple([e for e in l if e][:3] for l in data)
```

If you want only the non-empty items among the first three items of each list:

```
tuple([e for e in l[:3] if e] for l in data)
```

Comment: Hello Hyperboreus.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3116753 I have added an example with variable lengths.

Comment: Awesome. What if the goal is to limit to the 1st 3 objects for each? Thanks.

Comment: @user3116753 First non-empty three? Or non-empty of the first three? I have added both solutions.

Comment: This is perfect. You just gave me some ideas to try.

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` and `filter`

```
>>> l = (['2639123', 'LOUNGE & ENVIRONMENT', '"The lounge area was very dated and dirty. The garbage can by the popcorn was disgusting. The floor was very dirty, and the chairs were very dated and worn. "***', '', ''], ['2652943', 'LOUNGE & ENVIRONMENT', '"The lounge area seemed clean and updated, but it didn\'t feel very warm or welcoming. It seemed slightly closed off. The monkey I met all acknowledged me in a polite manner as I encountered them."***', '', ''])
>>> tuple(map(lambda x: filter(None, x), l))
(['2639123', 'LOUNGE & ENVIRONMENT', '"The lounge area was very dated and dirty. The garbage can by the popcorn was disgusting. The floor was very dirty, and the chairs were very dated and worn. "***'], ['2652943',  'LOUNGE & ENVIRONMENT',  '"The lounge area seemed clean and updated, but it didn\'t feel very warm or welcoming. It seemed slightly closed off. The monkey I met all acknowledged me in a polite manner as I encountered them."***'])
```

Comment: Hello Kroolik. Your solution does the trick. I think there may be cases where the structure may be more than 3 or less than 3. But This should be my very first step. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is really keep first tree elements of each list in the tuple:
(Assuming variable a is your tuple.)

```
b = (a[0][:3],a[1][:3])
```

Works, if your data structures are consistent.

Comment: This could work but when the data has inconsistency, it would be a problem. Thanks for the help nonetheless/

Comment: Sure, I know. (I even put it in the answer.) But it answers your question the way it is put ("retain first 3..."). So I just thought I would suggest something much simpler then the other answers, which seemed to still be a solution.